# most efficient way to quickly delete records using a join?

Tags: sql-server, database

What is the fastest way to delete records from a SQL Server database for a large year-end purge, when the query has to join to another table?  I understand cursors are slow.  Do I do

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1_id in (SELECT table1_id FROM table2 WHERE whatever)
```

Seems like it might be faster to join to the table inside the query using a different technique, something like

```
 DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1_id = table2
```

Comment: Joins are always faster, I believe.  Are you asking how to do a join?

Comment: I found the technique in http://www.johnsansom.com/fast-sql-server-delete/ to be surprisingly effective (I was skeptical when I read it). It refers to ordered deletes, but I imagine that extracting the subquery is the point and would apply in your scenario.

Comment: You should be looking at the execution plans before deciding, it is possible that the query optimizer comes up with the same execution plan in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

A join would be the best way to go.

I assume you have a foreign key association from `table2` to `table1`, so you're going to want to delete from the second table before the primary table.

Example:

```
DELETE T2
FROM table1 T1
JOIN table2 T2 ON -- JOIN CRITERIA HERE
WHERE -- FILTER CRITERIA HERE

DELETE T1
FROM table1 T1
JOIN table2 T2 ON -- JOIN CRITERIA HERE
WHERE -- FILTER CRITERIA HERE
```

If you attempt to delete from the primary table first, you will likely encounter a foreign key constraint violation.

Comment: Thanks all, I will use the join technique.  Would I be able to use the same technique for an UPDATE statement as well, without having to include a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a cascade delete relationship on the foreign key then get SQL server to cascade the delete for you?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would be faster.

delete from (select * FROM table1 WHERE table1_id in (SELECT table1_id FROM table2 WHERE whatever))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (should be faster than IN statement, because query stops than find first value in subquery and search next value):

```
DELETE t1
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 0 
              FROM table2 t2
              WHERE t1.table1_id = t2.table1_id 
              AND whatever)
```

Or you can do JOIN:

```
DELETE t1
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.table1_id = t2.table1_id 
WHERE whatever
```